# How much disk space do I need for running Parrot OS?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, partitioning, parrot-os

I just git a notebook from my uncle. The notebook already has Windows 8 x64bit installed but I want to dual boot with Parrot OS. My hard disk is 27GB and has about 13GB of free space in a partition.

Is that enough free space enough to dual boot Parrot OS??

Comment: Try to run it in a VM having just 13 GB space for it and you'll know the answer .

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, yes. Depending on which packages you want to use and/or how much free space you'll need for your own files, 8 GB should be plenty.

That being said, before you go on playing with partitions, I would strongly recommend you try it out with a virtual machine. Install VirtualBox, create a VM add test it. It might fit the bill for your needs.

Moreover [you can use a persistent USB stick](https://docs.parrotsec.org/doku.php/parrot-usb-live-persistence), so there's no real need to do a permanent install.

Comment: Is there any (semi-)official documentation that supports your "8GB should be plenty" statement? Or is this statement because you use Parrot OS and you're familiar enough with it? Both ways are OK. I'm just asking you to disclose whether the answer comes from theoretical research, actual experience or just a guess.

Comment: ParrotOS itself doesn't say anything, but the Raspberry Pi image they provide (and which I tried) is less than 6Gb, so it's a semi-official answer. I realize it's a different platform, so I also tried installing on a VM like I suggested. VirtualBox defaults to 8Gb for Debian installs, and Parrot Lite installs with ~1.7 Gb free space left. In the strictest sense of the definition, it does install. I leave to the user to determine if it's useful.

Comment: OK then. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it installed in your computer and to run it as it should/correctly you'll need 16GB of free space (In a VM as well as not dual-boot or directly in your HD).

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue.  I went and (on mackbook high Sierra-1 TB HDD) allocated drive space and then deleted all tries of install and reinstalled this time setting the VB allocated to red line then near full size of that partition which for me was just over 250GiB.  Parrot fired up and is almost done setting up now.  Woooo hoooo!!!!

In edit: I forgot to mention to delete old machines just use ctrl+click for options.  I didn't know how to delete old machines. So there I aired all my dirty laundry so someone else can get a few more zzz's than I did.  Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).